# Как создать линейный список?

Tags: алгоритм, c++

Люди, читал сегодня целый день про эти списки, но так и не понял, что и как. (( Я понял, что при работе со списком есть свои особенности... Но об этом спрошу позже, если появятся вопросы.  Дело в том, что я никак не могу понять, как создать линейный список, причем тут структура? Структура - это звено списка, а их объединение-список? В голове уже каша. Помогите, кто может, последовательно во всем разобраться.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот ссылки, по которым можно разобраться.

- [Введение в абстрактные структуры](http://algolist.manual.ru/ds/basic/index.php)
- [Динамический список, его реализация и применение](http://www.codenet.ru/progr/cpp/dlist.php)

Comment: Спасиб Лех, можно заглянуть к тебе?

Answer (score 3):

Линейный список, грубо говоря, набор "звеньев" для каждого из которых определено, какое звено идет перед ним и за ним. Соответственно есть первый элемент которому никто не предшествует, а так же последний, после которого не следует ни единый элемент. А уже внутри отдельного элемента может храниться любая структура.
Если список односвязен, то для каждого элемента будет определен лишь следующий элемент.

Comment: А можете написать хоть самый малый код на С++ с пояснениями к каждой строке??? Уж очень непонятен мне этот список(