# Создание нового элемента списка

Tags: c++

> Сделано вопросом из комментария в теме "[Как создать линейный список?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/29629/%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B9%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BA)" (@ХэшКод)

Написал код по ссылкам... Но никак не могу запустить функцию создания нового элемента... В чем ошибка?

```
// Включение в список нового компонента
void comp_in(list &l, char* n, char* v)
{
    Node* c = new Node();
    strcpy_s(c->name, 20, n);
    strcpy_s(c->value, 10, v);
    c->next = NULL;
    if (chk_empty(l))
        l.head = c;
    else
        l.tail->next = c;
    l.tail = c;
} 


void main(void)
{
    list vars; // Динамический список
    constr_list(vars);
    chk_empty(vars);
    //comp_in(vars);-та самая функция включения нового компонента
    getch();
}
```

Comment: Код всех функций и структур напишите. И еще, пишите конкретно, какие сообщения (про ошибку) Вы видите.

Answer (score 1):

Количество аргументов в функции 3, а вы передаете 1.

```
void main(void)
{
    list vars; // Динамический список
    char Name[20];
    char Value[10];
    int nValue;
    memset(Name,0,sizeof(Name));
    memset(Value,0,sizeof(Value));
    strcpy(Name,"Name");
    memcpy(Value,&nValue,sizeof(nValue));
    constr_list(vars);
    chk_empty(vars);
    comp_in(vars,Name,Value);\\долго не разбирался но должно работать
    getch();
}
```